# Can I set the cardinality of an entity_reference to a config entity?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I programmatically created an entity_reference (to a config entity) field via hook_entity_base_field_info (see code below).

All works fine until I try to define its cardinality. As soon as I add this, I get fatal error because Drupal can't find the database table user__foo.

```
  $fields['foo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setLabel(t('Foo field'))
    ->setDescription(t('Foo bar field'))
    ->setSetting('target_type', 'my_config_entity')
    ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
    //    ->setCardinality(\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
      'weight' => 6,
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'options_buttons',
      'weight' => 7,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, when doing a clean install with the cardinality uncommented, all works fine, so it's probably a matter of writing an update hook for existing sites to install storage for this new field (something done by drush entity-update earlier).